# Update Regex to exclude dots followed by anything but a whitespace

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm using to validate the format of names in my rails applications. I need to update it so it doesn't accept something like `mike.jones`

#### current regex

```
/([A-Za-z ',.-]+)/
```

#### acceptable names

```
'Baxter',
'Doe de Sour Jr.',
'Smith-Brown',
"Mathias d'Arras",
"d'Arras",
'King, Jr.',
'Cotton III'
```

#### invalid names

```
'Baxter2',
'user@gmail',
'#michael',
'tina.fay'
```

Comment: What about `Mr. Smith` or `J. K. Rowling`?

Comment: @CAustin Those should be valid

Comment: @CarySwoveland I did see the other answer. Although the accepted one fails on [rubular](https://rubular.com/r/NypFcxfbVkRn6T) it is passing in my [specs](https://gist.github.com/antarr/b6b551ddafd8e6791deb9cd1c7869785).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I may be changing the answer soon. There was a problem in my spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a bit complicated when you need to account for periods that occur in the middle of valid names. According to your description, the rule seems to be that periods are fine as long as they aren't immediately followed by letters. This can be accomplished with regex lookahead:

`^(?!.*\.\S)[A-Za-z ',.-]+$`

demo: https://regex101.com/r/LkUl38/2

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not sure if that's true. What if a period followed by a comma is valid, for example?

Comment: @AntarrByrd - It sounds like you don't know what you want. Please edit your answer to include which category you expect each of these to be in: `P.A.`, `P.A`, `p.a.`, `pa.`, `p.a.` and `PA.`

Comment: @Addison Yeah, I realized that. That's why I removed the comment. I'll exclude that example for now. Kind of hard for me to know what is valid since I wasn't given clear requirements.

Comment: Antarr, you merely need to make an assumption about what is required by you and frame your question accordingly. That's up to you--we don't want to hear about that. Examples are fine for helping readers understand the question but they are not a substitute for a precise statement of the problem. You need begin your question with something like, "I need to validate names in my application. Names may contain letters, whitespaces and any of the characters `',.-`, with the proviso that each period (if any) must be followed by a whitespace or be at the end of the string."

Answer (score 0):

Then you just need to move the `.` to the end of your regex (and escape it) so that you still get people with `Jr.` at the end of their name:

```
/([A-Za-z ',-]+\.?)/
```

And it should work fine. [Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/LkUl38/1)

There are some [great resources online](https://regexone.com/) for learning Regex, if you're interested.

Comment: That's not the regex at your link. Anchors? But what about `"Mr. Smith"`? (See comment on question.)